# Another WebDriverException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page that contains some JavaScript and performs some Ajax calls. When trying to test it using Selenium, I randomly get "PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM" message, maybe once in 5 runs.

Now I'm aware of the race issue between Ajax call and test engine, and I have taken steps to protect from it, but I still have some problem. My scenario is this: I change value of the select element 1 which triggers Ajax call that removes all option sub-elements of the select element 2 and generates new option sub-elements based on the Ajax response. Testing code:

```
    $this->select($this->byId('select1'))->selectOptionByValue('value1');
    $this->myWaitForElementToAppear('#select2>option[value="value2"]');
    $this->select($this->byId('select2'))->selectOptionByValue('value2');
```

last line triggers the error. Here is the myWaitForElementToAppear method:

```
public function myWaitForElementToAppear($selector, $limit = 5) {
    $start = time();
    while(true) {
        if($start + $limit < time()) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            $this->byCssSelector($selector);
            break;
        } catch(PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException $e) {}
    }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, myWaitForElementToAppear method should ensure that desired option has been added by jQuery before it exits and thus allow it to be used on the next line. I should add that I've made sure that time-out doesn't happen here (since my method allows for it to happen) and I'm positive that it's not the case

Edit: I should add that putting sleep(1) after myWaitForElementToAppear call solves the problem, but I don't understand why the additional second is needed. Shouldn't call to myWaitForElementToAppear be enough?

Answer (score 1):

There are some explanations [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/11/0):

> Firstly, time() has a very low precision, only returning the number of
>   whole seconds that have passed, which makes the whole thing quite
>   vague. Secondly, PHP has to sit there looping thousands of times while
>   it waits, essentially doing nothing. A much better solution is to use
>   the one of the two script sleep functions, sleep() and usleep(), which
>   take the amount of time to pause execution as their only parameter.

From php.net:

> The idea of sleep and usleep is that by letting the cpu run a few idle
>   cycles so the other programs can have some cycles run of their own.
>   what results in better response times and lower overall system-load.
>   so if you have to wait for something, go to sleep for a few seconds
>   instead of occupying the cpu while doing absolute nothing but
>   waitting.

And you can use [waitUntil](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/WaitUntil.php#L96) from PHPUnit:

```
/* waitElementToDisappear */
$this->waitUntil(function($testCase) {
    try {
        $input = $testCase->byCssSelector("#select2>option[value="value2"]");
    } catch (PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException $e) {
        if (PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException::NoSuchElement == $e->getCode()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}, 5000);

/* waitElementToAppear */
$this->waitUntil(function($testCase) {
    try {
        $input = $testCase->byCssSelector("#select2>option[value="value2"]");
        return true;
    } catch (PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException $e) {}
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I don't think that time is my problem. Its only purpose is to prevent me spending more then (roughly) 5 seconds on waiting for the JavaScript to do its magic, because that should be more then enough. Also I'm not concerned with freeing the CPU, until I solve the main problem, which is not finding element in the DOM, that should have already been there.

Now if I'm reading your code correctly, you return true if element is not found, which is exactly the opposite of what I need. I need exception not to be thrown on the line $input = ...

Comment: If you change your code into returning true only if element was found (exception was not thrown), then you basically get the function that does the exact same thing as mine does and that, unfortunately, is not working for me, which is the reason, I posted here in the first place. Am I reading your answer incorrectly?

Comment: You call _myWaitForElementToAppear_, but show us _myWaitForElementToDisappear_

Just move _return true_ after _$input=_ in my example with waitUntil

Comment: sry, that's my bad, I'll fix that. Fact remains that your soltuion, while not identical to mine, does the exact same thing, which is not enough to solve my problem. I acctually do have method myWaitForElementToDisappear, but it's not used here

Comment: Can you split you last line (which triggers the error) into 3 separeted lines? It can help identify error. And how do you rebuild options of select2: entire select or options only?

Comment: selectOptionByValue method is the one responsible for the error, which leads me to believe that desired option element was not yet rendered, even though myWaitForElementToAppear indicates it is. I remove only options of the select element and then add new ones based on Ajax response, select2 element is present at all times